# Exclamation Storing multiple function calls in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix-multiplication

My function returns an int array with 2 values 
Let's say, res[0] and res[1]

When I'm calling the array in a for loop for multiple times, and when I'm storing the results in another array, in each iteration the results are over-written with the new results.

If the first call returns [0,1] the array will store [0,1] at index [0] and [1], which is fine, but when I'm calling the function again, the new results are stored at the same indexes [0] and [1]
How can I avoid that?

Function Code:

```
 private void MatrixMul(string subInput, int[,] key, int [] result)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < key.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < key.GetLength(0); col++)
            {
               result[row]+= key[row, col] * AtoZ.IndexOf(subInput[col]);   
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < outPut.Length; i++)
            {
               MatrixMul(outPut[i], key,encChars);
            }
```

For example, my outPut contains the following: "TH","IS","AT"
when I'm calling the function with the first element of array "TH", it converts "T" to its equivalent number and apply some calculations and same with "H". Let's say the final answer is 20 for "T" and 30 for "H". 
The problem is that every time, encChars will store the values at index 0 and 1:
encChars[0]=20
encChars[1]=30
When I call the function again it will store the new values at 0 and 1.... That's because I'm not changing the index value for encChars on each call, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accumulate the values in the given array then do not create a new one inside your method, but declare it as a parameter and modify the values.

Comment: I want to have all the values from calling the function "i times" inside that array.. 
I didn't get what are you suggesting

Comment: It would help if you would post more of your calling code including an example input for your method and your expected results.